# Activity doesn't start when the app is in background

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an Android app that has LockScreen.

To make this, I created a Service and two Activities.

- ScreenLockService
- MainActivity
- LockScreenActivity

MainActivity is the main entrance activity.
Users can turn on/off the lock screen.

If the User turns on the LockScreen, the LockScreenActivity has appeared when the user turns on their device.

```kotlin
class ScreenLockService : Service() {

    private val receiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            when (intent?.action) {
                Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON -> {
                    val newIntent = Intent(context, ScreenLockActivity::class.java)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
                    context?.startActivity(newIntent)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerReceiver()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if (intent != null) {
            registerReceiver()
        }

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)

        return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    }

    private fun registerReceiver() {
        registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
    }

}
```

and this is the LockScreenActivity:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ScreenLockActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true)
            setTurnScreenOn(true)
            val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
            keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
        } else {
            window.addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)
        }

        setContent {
            ScreenLockTheme {
                ScreenLockScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the Manifest:

```xml
<service
    android:name=".service.ScreenLockService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<activity
    android:name=".ui.lock.ScreenLockActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true"
    android:showWhenLocked="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
```

The below scenario is working fine:

```
1. Run the app
2. Turn on the lock screen in MainActivity
3. Turn off the screen of device
4. Turn on the screen of device

-> LockScreenActivity has appeared!
```

But the below scenario doesn't work:

```
1. Run the app
2. Turn on the lock screen in MainActivity
3. Touch the home key (the app goes in the background)
3. Turn off the screen of device
4. Turn on the screen of device

-> LockScreenActivity hasn't appeared!
```

I added more logs and I found that `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` was called but it doesn't start the activity when the app was in the background or killed.

Why? and How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts